# JS retrieve first and last day of the year

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

Given a year I am trying to retrieve start and end of the current year (e.g. 01-01-XXXX 00:00 and 12-31-XXXX 23:59:59) however I am getting incorrect results.

My code:

```js
var date = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
var end_date = new Date(2020, 11, 31);
console.log(date, end_date);
```

Result:

`2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z 2020-12-30T23:00:00.000Z`

Weirdly enough this works fine if I run it in the browser console so I gues sit has to do with Node or my timezone?

Answer (score 0):

That code is correct to create dates for the start and end of the year in the *current environment's local timezone*.

When you log them to the console, their equivalent UTC dates are being displayed, and apparently, you are running this in a place where the time is UTC+1.

So if you want *local* Dates for the start and end of the year, that code is correct. If you want *UTC* dates for the start and end of the year, you can do this:

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1));
var end_date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 11, 31));
console.log(date, end_date);
```

The reason you are seeing differences between Node and your browser is that there is no standard for how dates are logged to the console. Node logs them in ISO Z-format (UTC), and some browsers log them as local time, which is precisely what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting right answer on browser console because **JavaScript is a client side scripting language** and browser interprets it on your local machine after successful request, therefore, taking your local time zone.
So if you write this JS code and run it on browser or any local JS environment, you will get correct results

But, **Node JS is server side framework derived from JavaScript**.
Which means anything written in Node JS or any server side language will be performed on server, and your code will consider time zone of the place where the server is located.

**So use JavaScript to display local time zone**.

Comment: Presumably, they are running Node on their own local machine. And as I have already stated in my answer, Node logs dates in UTC time, regardless of what the machine's time zone is.